# call javascript on document ready and partial view load complete

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I have a a page divided into 2 parts. One to show filter with checkbox and other for displaying content having paragraph.

On page load I will display the filter and paragraph content.
On click of filter checkbox, appropriate paragraph content satisfying the paragraph content will be loaded.

So the problem is I have a paragraph to display only 200 characters and hide the rest by showing "Read More...." text. On click of "Read More...." all the paragraph content will be displayed.

I have written the piece of code on document.ready method and this works fine for first time. Next time on selecting the filter checkbox, all the paragraph content will be displayed instead of only 200 characters.

NOTE : I have written the javascript in common.js file

To make this work on click of filter checkbox I have to rewrite this piece code in partial cshtml again instead of reusing the one in common.js file.
How do I make it to use function in common.js file.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var showChar = 500; // How many characters are shown by default
  var ellipsestext = "...";
  var moretext = "Read More >>";
  var lesstext = "Read Less";

  $('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if (content.length > showChar) {

      var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
      var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

      var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

      $(this).html(html);
    }

  });

  $('.morelink').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
      $(this).removeClass("less");
      $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("less");
      $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="more">                                                                                                    

       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse luctus mauris at scelerisque vestibulum. Nunc quis velit orci. Vivamus ut orci euismod, hendrerit risus eu, posuere turpis. Aenean posuere hendrerit tortor. Proin libero risus, ultricies id ex vel, congue posuere tortor. Duis cursus purus et turpis condimentum sagittis. Vivamus neque tellus, malesuada id feugiat in, suscipit ut odio<span class="moreellipses">...&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>. Fusce sed vehicula lectus, ac aliquam purus. Sed eleifend, massa eget maximus tincidunt, ante odio mattis arcu, eu viverra orci est eu libero. Quisque volutpat lacus eros, id aliquet sem egestas nec. Etiam tortor lectus, faucibus et justo eget, semper auctor lectus. Donec sed ligula at lorem fermentum varius vitae ac ante.</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">Read More &gt;&gt;</a></span></p>
```

Comment: Where is the checkbox ?

Comment: Why not just add a class name to style the paragraph to display ellipses (and toggle the class name to display the full text and truncated text) - [Truncate String with Ellipsis](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/)